# Powershell Exclude folders and files from the current directory and subdirectories from copying

Tags: powershell, copy-item, exclude-constraint

```
   $exclude = @(
        "AppData",
        "Application Data",
        "Contacts",
        "Cookies",
        "IntelGraphicsProfiles",
        "Local Settings",
        "LtcJobs",
        "NetHood",
        "PrintHood",
        "Recent",
        "SendTo",
        "Searches",
        "главное меню",
        "Мои документы",
        "Мои видеозаписи",
        "мои рисунки",
        "Моя музыка",
        "Music",
        "MicrosoftEdgeBackups",
        "Saved Games",
        "Links",
        "Шаблоны",
        "All Users",
        "Default",
        "Default User",
        "Все пользователи",
        "LocAdmin",
        "*_wa",
        "*_adm",
        "*cache*",
        "*Cache*",
        "ntuser*",
        "Ntuser*",
        "NTUSER*",
        "*.tmp",
        "*.temp",
        "~*",
        "*.bak",
        "*.ini"
    );

    Copy-Item "${from}Users\" -Exclude $exclude -Recurse "$destinationFolderPath\Users\" -Force -PassThru *>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath $pathToLogFile -Append;
```

There is the following code, is it possible to somehow correct it so that it excludes folders and files from the `$exclude` from copying, both in the current directory and in its subdirectories?

I tried adding * `("${from}Users\*")`. But it doesn't work with subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `robocopy` better

Notes:

if you want to delete the extra files in the destination use argument /mir
and arg /e is to include subdirectories like recurse

```
  $excludeDir = @(
  "*Data",
  "Application Data",
  "Contacts"
)
$excludeFiles = @(
  "*.txt",
  "*.csv",
  "*.json"
)

robocopy C:\source C:\destination /XD  $excludeDir /XF $excludeFiles /e /mir
```

Comment: Thank you!
Could you help clear this up a little more?
According to your recommendation it gives an error: `ERROR: Invalid parameter #3: "/XD AppData /XD Application"`
Could you explain in more detail why, as I understand it, you add this to each element of the array: ``"$_`""`, what do these symbols mean? And then, it turns out, you glue all the elements of the array into one line? This is done as follows: The utility cannot work with an array, do I understand correctly?

Comment: please check as the Ans edited

Comment: for more details see this https://superuser.com/questions/482112/using-robocopy-and-excluding-multiple-directories

Comment: Thanks a lot, based on your help, this helped:
```robocopy "${from}Users\" "$destinationFolderPath\Users\" /XD $excludeDir /XF $excludeFiles /s /mir /unilog+:$pathToLogFile /tee;```